# Using Dynamic Navigation Menu In Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I am Using **Oracle Apex 5** For My applications. I have Created a Dynamic Navigation Menu List. But I want to Customize and The Menu Like Shop.oracle.com Menu.

I have created a header Like shop.oracle.com. header. Just I want to click on Browse Item and Open My navigation Menu. Or On Button Click Open a Dynamic Navigation Menu.

Like Browse Button Click Open The Menu:

[image: Like Browse Button Click Open The Menu]

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic navigation list APEX 5](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3758579) try this page

[Here is an another  example](http://davidsgale.com/apex-5-0-how-to-dynamic-menus-universal-theme/)